# Multithreading program does not work correctly on one-core processor

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing multithreading program for reading and viewing in comfortable form Apache log files. It works, but it doesn't work correctly on an one-core processor. I assume where is error in, but I don't know what I need to change. Assuming error has been written in comment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace lab2Form
{
    class LogStruct
    {
        public Dictionary<string, ulong> domainName;
        public Dictionary<string, ulong> URL;
        public Dictionary<string, ulong> domainData;
        public Dictionary<string, ulong> errorCodes;

        public LogStruct()
        {
            domainName = new Dictionary<string, ulong> { };
            URL = new Dictionary<string, ulong> { };
            domainData = new Dictionary<string, ulong> { };
            errorCodes = new Dictionary<string, ulong> { };
        }
    }

    class CLogParser
    {
        LogStruct m_logStruct;

        public CLogParser()
        {
             m_logStruct = new LogStruct();
        }

        public void ThreadProc(object param)
        {
            string logName = (string)param;

            StreamReader file;
            try
            {
                file = new StreamReader(logName);
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
            string line;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)//may be,something wrong here
            {
                var space_pos = line.IndexOf(' ');
                if (space_pos > 0)
                {
                    string[] parameters = line.Split(new Char[] { ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    string domainName = parameters[0];
                    bool isMainPage = (parameters[4] == "\"-\"") ? true : false;
                    string relativePageAddress = (isMainPage) ? "/" : parameters[5];
                    Regex reg = new Regex(" \\d+");
                    MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(line);
                    string errorCode = matches[1].Value;
                    ulong pageSize = (matches.Count > 2) ? Convert.ToUInt64(matches[2].Value) : 0;
                    string fullAdress = domainName + relativePageAddress;
                    string fullErrCode = domainName + errorCode;

                    if (m_logStruct.domainName.ContainsKey(domainName))
                    {
                        lock (m_logStruct.domainName)
                        {
                            m_logStruct.domainName[domainName]++;
                        }
                        lock (m_logStruct.domainData)
                        {
                            m_logStruct.domainData[domainName] += pageSize;
                        }
                        if (m_logStruct.URL.ContainsKey(fullAdress))
                        {
                            lock (m_logStruct.URL)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.URL[fullAdress]++;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lock (m_logStruct.URL)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.URL.Add(fullAdress, 1);
                            }
                        }
                        if (m_logStruct.errorCodes.ContainsKey(fullErrCode))
                        {
                            lock (m_logStruct.errorCodes)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.errorCodes[fullErrCode]++;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lock (m_logStruct.errorCodes)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.errorCodes.Add(fullErrCode, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lock (m_logStruct.domainName)
                        {
                            m_logStruct.domainName.Add(domainName, 1);
                        }
                        lock (m_logStruct.URL)
                        {
                            m_logStruct.domainData.Add(domainName, pageSize);
                        }
                        lock (m_logStruct.domainData)
                        {
                            m_logStruct.URL.Add(fullAdress, 1);
                        }
                        lock (m_logStruct.errorCodes)
                        {
                            m_logStruct.errorCodes.Add(fullErrCode, 1);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        public void ShowData(ref DataGridView dmRequests, ref DataGridView URL, ref DataGridView dmData, ref DataGridView errorCodes)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> dmReqList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();
            List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> urlReqList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>(); 
            List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> dmDataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();
            List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> errCodesList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();

            lock (m_logStruct.domainName)`enter code here`
            {
                dmReqList = m_logStruct.domainName.ToList();
            }
            lock(m_logStruct.URL)
            {
                urlReqList = m_logStruct.URL.ToList();
            }
            lock(m_logStruct.domainData)
            {
                dmDataList = m_logStruct.domainData.ToList();
            }
            lock(m_logStruct.errorCodes)
            {
                errCodesList = m_logStruct.errorCodes.ToList();
            }

            dmRequests.DataSource = dmReqList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
            URL.DataSource = urlReqList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
            dmData.DataSource = dmDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
            errorCodes.DataSource = errCodesList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your evidence for it not working on a one-core processor?

Comment: `while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)` is with a local file and so absoutely not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the `ConcurrentDictionary` of .NET4? The hard work of ensuring thread safety in dictionaries has already been done. Your code would be much cleaner and less error prone. Maybe it solves your problem, maybe it doesn't. (You still haven't described the symptoms of "not working". Does it run as a single-threaded app? Does it crash? Does it produce wrong data?)

```
class LogStruct
{
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> domainName;
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> URL;
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> domainData;
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> errorCodes;

    public LogStruct()
    {
        domainName = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> { };
        URL = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> { };
        domainData = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> { };
        errorCodes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> { };
    }
}

class CLogParser
{
    LogStruct m_logStruct;

    public CLogParser()
    {
         m_logStruct = new LogStruct();
    }

    public void ThreadProc(object param)
    {
        string logName = (string)param;

        StreamReader file;
        try
        {
            file = new StreamReader(logName);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)//may be,something wrong here
        {
            var space_pos = line.IndexOf(' ');
            if (space_pos > 0)
            {
                string[] parameters = line.Split(new Char[] { ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string domainName = parameters[0];
                bool isMainPage = (parameters[4] == "\"-\"") ? true : false;
                string relativePageAddress = (isMainPage) ? "/" : parameters[5];
                Regex reg = new Regex(" \\d+");
                MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(line);
                string errorCode = matches[1].Value;
                ulong pageSize = (matches.Count > 2) ? Convert.ToUInt64(matches[2].Value) : 0;
                string fullAdress = domainName + relativePageAddress;
                string fullErrCode = domainName + errorCode;

                if (m_logStruct.domainName.ContainsKey(domainName))
                {
                    m_logStruct.domainName[domainName]++;
                    m_logStruct.domainData[domainName] += pageSize;
                    m_logStruct.URL.AddOrUpdate(fullAdress, 1, (key, oldVal) =>
                    {
                        m_logStruct.URL[fullAdress]++;
                        return m_logStruct.URL[fullAdress];
                    });

                    m_logStruct.errorCodes.AddOrUpdate(fullErrCode, 1, (key, oldVal) =>
                    {
                        m_logStruct.errorCodes[fullErrCode]++;
                        return m_logStruct.errorCodes[fullErrCode];
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    m_logStruct.domainName.AddOrUpdate(domainName, 1, ShallNeverHappen);
                    m_logStruct.domainData.AddOrUpdate(domainName, pageSize, ShallNeverHappen);
                    m_logStruct.URL.AddOrUpdate(fullAdress, 1, ShallNeverHappen);
                    m_logStruct.errorCodes.AddOrUpdate(fullErrCode, 1, ShallNeverHappen);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ulong ShallNeverHappen(String key, ulong existingVal) 
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("This method is not expected to be called");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I will try it later.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing shared state from multiple threads in a racy way with at least one of them being a writer.

Example:

```
if (m_logStruct.URL.ContainsKey(fullAdress)) //unsynchronized read
```

The rules of threading say that you cannot safely do that.

I don't see what's supposed to be wrong with the line you marked. The stream is thread-local. It is not being used in a racy way.

Comment: May be, error isn't in this line, I assume, what error may be in critical sections(locks) or in reading files on one core processor

Comment: It is an error and but only because of the `m_logStruct.URL.Add()`. They would both have to be in a `lock()`.